# Как посмотреть дерево xaml после компиляции?

Tags: wpf, xaml

У меня есть xaml код, и я бы очень хотел посмотреть, что он из себя представляет со всеми стилями и шаблонами во время выполнения, как это сделано с кодом html в браузерах. Это возможно сделать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для Visual Studio 2015 вы можете использовать [Live Visual tree](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/08/01/debugging-xaml.aspx). В более старых версиях используйте менее удобный [WPF tree visualizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd409789.aspx): если у вас есть wpf-объект, вы можете подсмотреть его visual tree на breakpoint'е.

Кроме того, есть отличная утилита [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), которая (по крайней мере *до* появления Live Visual tree) незаменима при WPF-разработке.

Comment: Я не нашел как скачать по вашей ссылке Live Visual tree, но за Snoop огромное спасибо!

Comment: @iRumba: Скачивать не надо, он должен быть встроен в Visual Studio.

Comment: Ага, нашел, спасибо. Только я не вижу его преимуществ. Во первых, студия перекрывает окно самого приложения своим телом на полный экран, а значит приходится постоянно переключаться с дерева на окно. Во вторых снуп позволяет выполнять методы, а во встроенной утилите я этого не нашел. К тому же я не смог на ходу изменить BackGround окна во встроенной утилите. Мне это не очень то и нужно, но понадобится с другими свойствами.

Comment: @iRumba: Значит, в любом случае snoop просто необходим.